# Monad transformers monad duplication

Tags: haskell, io, monads, monad-transformers, option-type

I am new to monad transformers, so sorry easy question.
I have value `val :: MaybeT IO String` and function `fn :: String -> IO [String]`.
So after binding, I have `val >>= liftM fn :: MaybeT IO (IO [String])`. How can I remove duplicate IO monad and get result of type `MaybeT IO [String]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `lift` (or `liftIO`) instead of `liftM`.

```
> :t val >>= lift . fn
val >>= lift . fn :: MaybeT IO [String]
```

`liftM` is for applying pure functions in a monad. `lift` and `liftIO` are for lifting actions into a transformer.

```
liftM  :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
lift   :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```